# Magento2. client denied by server configuration on hosting error report

Tags: magento2, server-setup, magento2.4.2, apache, apache2

client denied by server configuration on hosting error report
When I check Cpanel errors I can see below errors appear lot of time

AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/b/public_html/app/etc/config.php

Comment: Have you modify anything into the config.php?

Comment: No, after changing the server I am facing this issue.